# Get Locale ID for users ODFB site collections in tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, onedrive-for-business

I am trying to get a list of users OneDrive For Business site collections Locale ID's. I have been trying to use [this site](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/04/13/office-365-change-the-locale-of-all-onedrive-for-business-sites-using-powershell/) to help me achieve this. I have changed the bottom section to try and get the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RegionalSettings.LocaleId` for each site collection but I cannot seem to pull anything back for the LocaleID

```
#Create People Manager object to retrieve profile data
$PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {
    $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
    $Context.Load($UserProfile)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
        {
        Write-Host "User:" $User.LoginName -ForegroundColor Green
        #Bind to OD4B Site and change locale
        $OD4BSiteURL = $UserProfile.PersonalUrl
        $Context2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($OD4BSiteURL)
        Write-Host "localeID:" $OD4BSiteURL.RegionalSettings.LocaleId -ForegroundColor Yellow

        }}
```

Would someone be able to assist to let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some fiddling I got it. Don't know if it is the most streamlined way but it works well.

Here is my full script if anyone ever finds they need to do the same -

```
        #Add references to SharePoint client assemblies and authenticate to Office 365 site – required for CSOM
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles")




        #Specify tenant admin
        $User = "ADMINACCOUNT"
        $Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
        $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$Password)


        #Configure MySite Host URL
        $SiteURL = "https://TENANT-admin.sharepoint.com/"


        #Bind to MySite Host Site Collection
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Context.Credentials = $Creds


        #Identify users in the Site Collection
        $Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
        $Context.Load($Users)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()



$PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)
Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {
    $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
    $Context.Load($UserProfile)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null)
        {
        Write-Host "User:" $User.LoginName -ForegroundColor Green
        #Bind to OD4B Site and change locale
        $OD4BSiteURL = $UserProfile.PersonalUrl
        $Context2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($OD4BSiteURL)
        Write-Host $OD4BSiteURL -ForegroundColor Yellow

        Foreach ($User in $OD4BSiteURL)
{
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("$user")
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)


$web = $ctx.Web;
$RegionalSettings = $ctx.Web.RegionalSettings
$ctx.Load($web);
$ctx.Load($RegionalSettings);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

Write-Host $User $RegionalSettings.LocaleId

}
        }}
```